# Dismiss a confirm / alert dialog from a javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to use a bookmarklet to fill up a form and click the submit button on a webpage (I have no control over the webpage content). 
After the submit button is pressed, there is a popup confirmation box where I have to click `OK` . This last step breaks the automation. How do I automatically dismiss the popup from the bookmarklet (javascript) ?

Comment: I assume that popup is a confirm ``return conform('question?');``, I guess you should change that with whatever you need eg: ``return myAuto();``

Comment: I do no have control over the webpage, where do I change it?

Comment: If you don't have control ... sorry, no cannot do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dialog is an alert dialog (usually, it has `OK` and `Cancel` buttons), you could override the `confirm()` method to always return true, which is what happens when you click `OK`:

```
window.confirm = function(){return true;};
```

If your dialog is an alert dialog (usually, it has only an `OK` button), you need to override the `alert()` method to just return nothing (`undefined`):

```
window.alert = function(){};
```

They must be set before the `confirm()` or `alert()` methods are called by the webpage.